# Does probability measure on cartesian product of finite set allow "nothing" to happen?

Tags: probability-theory

That is, suppose we have a finite set $X$, and a probability measure $P:X\times X\to [0,1]$

Is it possible for "nothing" to occur?

I.e., suppose $X=\{A,B\}$,

Then we know the following must be defined: $P(A,A); P(A,B); P(B,A), P(B,B)$.

Must these sum up to 1, or is it possible that "nothing" occurs (and takes up there remaining probability).

If "nothing" is not allowed to occur, what could we change to make it possible? Add the empty set to $X$?

Comment: The probability axioms require $P(X \times X) = 1$ and also require additivity of finitely many (or countably many) disjoint outcomes, so we must also have $P(A,A) + P(A,B) + P(B,A) = P(B,B) = P(\{(A,A)\}\cup \{(A,B)\}\cup \{(B,A)\} \cup \{(B,B)\}) = P(X \times X) = 1$.

Comment: Note that $P$ is not defined on $X\times X$.

Answer (score 0):

Measure of an empty set is 0 by definition. Measure of the set X on which you define a probability is 1, also by definition of a probability measure. If you add the empty set to X, then it may be the case that the measure (probability) of the set containing an empty set (`{∅}`) is non-zero, but the measure of the empty set itself (`∅`) is still zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).